# Google Charts bar chart last value label cutoff

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I've tried looking for a fix to this problem but wasn't able to find one that pertained to the haxis labels...

In the picture below, you'll notice that the last percentage label on the haxis is not showing up. I'm not sure what the issue is. I've tried messing around with the chartArea width and left values but that didnt seem to work. I've also made sure that the containing div is wide enough so it's not cutting off the '100%' label.

Any ideas?

[image]

**Update w/ jsFiddle**

[jsFiddle with my code](http://jsfiddle.net/gthoma2/sbo2ggp3/)

```
<body bgcolor = "black">

    <div id="chart_language_div"></div>

    <div id="chart_api_div"></div>

    <div id="chart_software_div"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see from my div declarations, I don't have any containing divs in the example and the issue still exists.

Comment: Can we see some code? Find a selector matching those labels and add css to set `overflow: visible;`. If it still doesn't show up then you can rule out clipping.

Comment: So I went into chrome dev tools and located the elements that form the haxis labels. I applied 'overflow: visible;' to the elements but it's still not appearing. When I look at the element tree of the graph I see entries for every haxis and vaxis label EXCEPT the last one... it's like it's not even producing it (maybe that's how it should work anyways-- if you don't see it on the page it's because it's not populating the element tree at all). I'll update my op with some code.

Comment: I'm guessing that didn't work? At this point seeing a jsfiddle is the only way I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem code

```
chartArea: {left: 140, width:'80%', height:'70%'},
```

Here is a solution

```
chartArea: {left: 140, width: 420, height:'70%'},
```

Basically, you were right about the label not being created. Looks like Google is checking the chart width before making the label, so rather than the browser clipping the label, Google charts never creates it.

So with a containing div of 580, a left attribute of 140, and a chart width of 80% (464px), you were overflowing. The math is 464+140 = 604, which is greater than your containing element width (580). Setting the width to a flat 420 gives you 120+420=560, leaving 20px for the label on the right side.

I'd recommend never mixing percentages and fixed widths (that goes for every layout engine I've dealt with). Having a percentage height and fixed width is fine.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbo2ggp3/4/